How to run a 'container-like' thing inside a non-privileged docker container?
I have access to a docker container running CentOS 7 and I do not have access to the host machine. Since the OS is pretty old, I want to find a way to run ubuntu 20.04 inside that container.
I have tried to use podman, runc, sysbox, and even chroot+mount. But as the container is non-privileged, I cannot mount /proc or /dev, or use /sys/cgroup. Is there any way to achieve what I want?
